# extract data from csv file and put to 2D Array - refactoring

Tags: java, file, csv, refactoring, multidimensional-array

I need read data from csv file and much more convinience for me is put there to 2D array (to my mind it's easiest way to work with this "schedule" data).
Each file line contained information in following format:

`Instructor, Course, Group, Student, Result`

as follows example:

```
Paul Schwartz,Introduction to Computer Architecture,I1,Ben Dunkin,88
Muhamed Olji,Object Oriented Programming,I4,Mike Brown,73
```

But my code needs some simplify. But I don't know how to make it easier and ask of ***You***.

**Code:**

```
private String[][] fileContent(String pathToCSVFile) {
    final int ROWS = 100;
    final int COLUMNS = 5;
    String fileData[][] = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pathToCSVFile);
    boolean done = false;
    int i, j;

    while (!done) {
        for (i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
           for (j = 0; j >= 0; j++) {
               String str[] = scanner.nextLine().split(","); 
               for (int element = 0; element < str.length; element++) {
                   fileData[i][element] = str[element];
                   if (i >= ROWS) {
                       Arrays.copyOf(fileData, fileData.length * 2);
                   }
               }                   
           }
        }

        if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) done = true;
    }

    return  fileData;
}
```

- How to refactor this snippet of code for better simplicity?
- Does exist any better way for partially filled array (than `Arrays.copyOf(fileData, fileData.length * 2)`)?

Comment: If simplicity is your goal, use a CSV library, such as openCSV, which has a `List<String[]> lines = new CSVReader(reader).readAll();` method... Your method then becomes a one-liner (ok maybe two).

Comment: Consider posting such questions on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  The site should be more suitable.

Comment: @assylias I [tried this way](http://pastebin.com/sfizSsuc) but some problem to convert from List to arrays it's a little bit problematic. Any suggestion are available here too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using openCSV, you can get a list containing all the lines and convert it to an array (or just keep the list):

```
try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new BufferedReader(
          new FileReader(pathToCSVFile)));) {

    List<String[]> lines = reader.readAll();
    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()][]);
}
```

(using Java 7 try-with-resources syntax)

Comment: Some little issue we need after doing this reading extract right data. How does split this one string and will use in future?

Comment: You have a 2D array containing all the fields in your csv. You can just loop and get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be careful with those for loops. They are "almost" undefined loops, because they start with i,j=0, and loop while >=0 (always, until they overflow into a negative number).
And why do you need them anyway? I think with you while and the for(element) you are done, right?
Something like that (I didn't tried, is just to explain the concept)

```
private String[][] fileContent(String pathToCSVFile) {
    final int ROWS = 100;
    final int COLUMNS = 5;
    String fileData[][] = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pathToCSVFile);
    boolean done = false;
    int i=0;

    while (!done) {
        String str[] = scanner.nextLine().split(","); 
        for (int element = 0; element < str.length; element++) {
            fileData[i][element] = str[element];
            if (i >= ROWS) {
                Arrays.copyOf(fileData, fileData.length * 2);
            }
        }
        if (!scanner.hasNextLine())
            done = true;
        else
            i++;
    }
    return  fileData;
}
```

By the way, why don't you use objects, like an ArrayList? It would make your life easier, so you don't have to worry about memory handling. You just add new objects.

Something like an `ArrayList <ArrayList <String>>`

Comment: I agree with you that use object is much more convenience but I'll need sort the `Result` and `Group` and show the top of student as `1. Ben Dunkin  88;`. But I don't know how to exactly sort this `<ArrayList <String>` and after this show gather with student name?

Comment: Actually, sort an ArrayList is really easy, either implementing Comparable or using the Comparator.
The elegant solution would be to implement a class (or more than one, depending on your needs) that represents your row, and that implements the Comparable interface. After this, if you have an `ArrayList <YourClass> al;` you can do `Collections.sort(al);` to sort your array.
And all these objects initialized with the OpenCSV library, of course. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel.